# Trying to bind keystrokes to a menu item

Tags: key-bindings, auctex

I have a menu item added to AucTex's Command Menu, Latexindent.  This calls an external process and is added in mu .emacs file by the following:

```
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
              '("Latexindent" "latexindent -w -s %a"
            TeX-run-command nil t
             :help "Run Latexindent on file.")))
```

I'm trying to bind this a keystoke series C-c i using the following:

```
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
   (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      (set-keymap-parent map TeX-mode-map)
      (define-key map "\C-ci" 'forward-char)))
```

Unfortunately, this is not defining the C-c i at all, much less to a menu item.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this defined correctly?

Shawn Way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're expecting TeX-mode-map to know that it has a 'child', but that's not the way keymap inheritance works.

Any reason you can't just make the change directly in `TeX-mode-map`? Or use `local-set-key` in the major modes setup hook. e.g.

```
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (define-key TeX-mode-map "\C-ci" 'forward-char))
```

Comment: No reason other than I don't know how...

Comment: `(define-key TeX-mode-map "\C-ci" 'forward-char)` should do it